# Execute function when variable is true or becomes true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `MyExampleController` controller which depends on certain available data. For example - on `myService` service which has that data in it if `myService.dataIsAvailable()` is `true`. Now then I access certain controller, I want to check if it returns `true`, if yes, `init();`, otherwise if it ever becomes `true`, fire the `init();`. How do I do it?

```
angular.module('angularUiApp').controller('MyExampleController', function()     {
    function init() {
        console.log('do some stuff');
    }

    // init single time only when myService.dataIsAvailable() is true or execute init() when myService.dataIsAvailable() becomes true.
    init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own peace of code

```
var initInterval = null;
var timeMs = 100;

initInterval = $interval(function () {
    if (myService.dataAvailable()) {
        $interval.cancel(initInterval);
        init();
    }
}, timeMs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject your service to your controller and check for the value you need, else wait

```
angular.module('angularUiApp').controller('MyExampleController', ['myService', function(myService)     {
    function init() {
        if(!myService.dataIsAvailable()){
           setTimeout(function () { // try again later - you could do that with a while loop also, whatever suits your needs
                            init();
             }, 400);
         else{
           // do stuff
         }
       }
    }

    // init single time only when myService.dataIsAvailable() is true or execute init() when myService.dataIsAvailable() becomes true.
    init();
}]);
```

p.s.: make sure `myService` script is loaded before the controller script.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the data from the service and execute the init function when the data becomes true. So the code will be as:

angular.module('angularUiApp')
.controller('MyExampleController',[
    '$interval',
    'myService',
    function($interval, myService){

```
    var checkingForData;

    function init() {
        console.log('do some stuff');
    }

    var doSomeTask = function(){
        /* init single time only when myService.dataIsAvailable() is true or execute init()
        when myService.dataIsAvailable() becomes true. */
        init();
        if(checkingForData) $interval.cancel(checkingForData); // cancel interval after getting data
    };

    checkingForData = $interval(function(){
        if(myService.dataIsAvailable()){
            doSomeTask();
        }
    }, 1000);

}
```

]);

I hope it will work.